# Can I run a non .NET Core project with Visual Studio Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

My project targets .NET 4.6.1. Is it in principle possible to get this running with with Visual Studio for MacOS? If so, what are common bottlenecks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the current version of Visual Studio for Mac can only target .NET Core. See the compatibility specs here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-mac

Comment: More explicitly, there is no .NET Framework 4.6.1 on macOS. Mono is not .NET Framework (though it supports some .NET Framework 4.6.1 API).